# Travel insurance (medical costs) when traveling from UK to Spain (Fuerteventura)

Tags: uk, spain, covid-19, insurance, ehic

I am a UK resident (Swiss citizen) and will be traveling from the UK to Fuerteventura next week. At this point, the FCO advice is to avoid all but essential travel.

The airline offers a free date change in case I need to change flights. My question is regarding medical expenses: If due to COVID or otherwise, I am required to visit a hospital during this trip, what insurance can I purchase to cover these expenses? It appears that most insurance companies simply do not cover any medical expenses if travel is to a country that the FCO advises against travel to.

I also have an EHIC card.

Comment: Is your travel there essential?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Entitlements under EHIC, such as ordinary and emergency treatments at public hospitals (including for Covid), are not affected; for UK, that is until at earliest December 31, 2020. After the date, EHICs issued by UK become invalid with some exceptions (e.g. current pensioners and students in EU).

For things EHIC doesn't cover, like private treatments, rescuing and repatriation, there are still companies offering limited coverage.

For example, staysure offers an European FCO Travel Advice Extension (but not covering Coronavirus-related claims): https://www.staysure.co.uk/fco-advice-travel-insurance/.

Avanti: https://www.avantitravelinsurance.co.uk/fco-advice-travel-insurance

Battleface: https://www.battleface.com/ which claims to cover Covid-related medical expenses as well.

But of course small prints may apply and you should check details of the policy offers to see if they suit you.